# Numpy Search & Slice 3D Array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, 3d, slice

I'm very new to Python & Numpy and am trying to accomplish the following:

Given, 3D Array:

```
arr_3d = [[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]],
          [[3,2,1],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]]
          [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[0,0,0]]]
arr_3d = np.array(arr_3d)
```

1. Get the indices where `[0,0,0]` appears in the given 3D array.
2. Slice the given 3D array from where `[0,0,0]` appears first.

In other words, I'm trying to remove the padding (In this case: `[0,0,0]`) from the given 3D array.

Here is what I have tried,

```
arr_zero = np.zeros(3)
for index in range(0, len(arr_3d)):
    rows, cols = np.where(arr_3d[index] == arr_zero)
    arr_3d[index] = np.array(arr_3d[0][:rows[0]])
```

But doing this, I keep getting the following error:

> Could not broadcast input array from shape ... into shape ...

I'm expecting something like this:

```
[[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]],
 [[3,2,1]]
 [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]]
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Updated the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the first occurance of those indices with `all()` reduction alongwith `argmax()` and then slice each `2D` slice off the `3D` array -

```
In [106]: idx = (arr_3d == [0,0,0]).all(-1).argmax(-1)

# Output as list of arrays
In [107]: [a[:i] for a,i in zip(arr_3d,idx)]
Out[107]: 
[array([[1, 2, 3],
        [4, 5, 6]]), array([[3, 2, 1]]), array([[1, 2, 3],
        [4, 5, 6],
        [7, 8, 9]])]

# Output as list of lists
In [108]: [a[:i].tolist() for a,i in zip(arr_3d,idx)]
Out[108]: [[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]], [[3, 2, 1]], [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]]
```

Comment: I see my answer is quite similar to yours, but yours is better (will delete).

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Not really similar (so you could have kept it), but I guess `argmax` would be faster though.